# A program that expands a list of maps and chooses a random element

Tags: beginner, clojure

This is the essence of chapter 3 of "Clojure for the Brave and True".
This program is about completing the list `asym-hobbit-body-parts` by adding a given number of elements called `"0-<name>"` `"1-<name>"` and so on for every element in `asym-hobbit-body-parts` that starts with "left" and subsequently choosing a random body part to hit.
This contains code from the book which I rewrote from memory after finishing chapter 3. (And I mixed it with what I learned on the [official homepage](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/syntax))

I am very curious what a clean version of this would look like.

```
(ns clojure-noob.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [clojure.string :as str] ))


(def asym-hobbit-body-parts [{:name "head" :size 3}
                             {:name "left-eye" :size 1}
                             {:name "left-ear" :size 1}
                             {:name "mouth" :size 1}
                             {:name "nose" :size 1}
                             {:name "neck" :size 2}
                             {:name "left-shoulder" :size 3}
                             {:name "left-upper-arm" :size 3}
                             {:name "chest" :size 10}
                             {:name "back" :size 10}
                             {:name "left-forearm" :size 3}
                             {:name "abdomen" :size 6}
                             {:name "left-kidney" :size 1}
                             {:name "left-hand" :size 2}
                             {:name "left-knee" :size 2}
                             {:name "left-thigh" :size 4}
                             {:name "left-lower-leg" :size 3}
                             {:name "left-achilles" :size 1}
                             {:name "left-foot" :size 2}])


(defn make-sym-parts [asym-set num]
  (reduce (fn [sink, {:keys [name size] :as body-part}]
           (if (str/starts-with? name "left-")
             (into sink (apply vector body-part 
                         (for [i (range num)]
                           {:name (str/replace name #"^left" (str i))
                            :size size})))
             (conj sink body-part)))
           []
           asym-set))


(defn rand-part [parts]
  (let [size-sum (reduce + (map :size parts))
        thresh (rand size-sum)]
    (loop [[current & remaining] parts
           sum (:size current)]
      (if (> sum thresh)
        (:name current)
        (recur remaining (+ sum (:size (first remaining))))))))


(defn -main
  [& arg]
  (println (rand-part (make-sym-parts asym-hobbit-body-parts 3))))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I adjusted the title. But I think you pasted the wrong link ^^

Comment: Ah, seems the "meta" disappeared from the URL in in my template file. Apologies, the correct URL is https://CodeReview.Meta.StackExchange.com/q/2436 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually already fixed up the main thing that I was going to comment on: your previous use of `def` over `let`. Just to emphasize on why it's important to choose one over the other though:

```
(defn f []
  (def my-var 5))

(f)

(println my-var)
5  ; It leaked the state of the function and polluted the namespace
```

---

Beyond that, this isn't bad code. As I mentioned on SO, I'm a little rusty, so hopefully someone else will go a little more in-depth. I'll mention what I see here though:

This might be a little over-engineering, but I don't like how the `asym-hobbit-body-parts` definition is repeating the keys `:name` and `:size` over and over. This allows typos to slip in, and makes more work for you if you want to add more parts. I'd make a "constructor" that automatically creates the maps from the data:

```
(defn new-part [part-name part-size]
  {:name part-name, :size part-size})

(def asym-hobbit-body-parts [(new-part "head" 3)
                             (new-part "left-eye" 1)
                             (new-part "left-ear" 1)])
```

I like this because now there's a function that definitively says what a "part" is defined as, and if you ever want to change what keywords you use, you only need to change `new-part` now.

This still has duplication though, and could be reduced down with a helper that auto-wraps vector "tuples":

```
(defn new-parts [& name-size-pairs]
  (mapv #(apply new-part %) name-size-pairs))
  ; or (mapv (partial apply new-part) name-size-pairs))  ; Partially apply "apply"

(def asym-hobbit-body-parts3 (new-parts
                               ["head" 3]
                               ["left-eye" 1]
                               ["left-ear" 1]))
```

Or, if you want to get rid of the need for the wrapping vectors, you can use `partition` to cut a list of attributes into 2s:

```
(defn new-parts [& name-size-pairs]
  (->> name-size-pairs
       (partition 2)  ; Cut the list into pairs of 2
       (mapv #(apply new-part %))))

(def asym-hobbit-body-parts3 (new-parts
                               "head" 3,
                               "left-eye" 1,
                               "left-ear" 1))
```

It really depends on how you want it to read.

In case you aren't familiar with them, I highly recommend practicing use of [`->`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E) and [`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E). They seem a little complicated at first, but once you understand them, they have the potential to make your code much neater. They allow your code to read more easily as a series of transformations.

---

I think the reduction in `make-sym-parts` is too big. When I have a call to `reduce` with a large reducing function like that, I try to move it out into its own standalone function. That gives that code a name to make it clearer what it's doing, and makes the call to `reduce` easier to understand. I decided just to make it a local function using [`letfn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/letfn). You could also make it a global function using `defn`; but I don't think that's necessary.

```
(defn make-sym-parts [asym-set num]
  (letfn [(transform-lefts [sink {:keys [name] :as body-part}]
            (if (str/starts-with? name "left-")
              (into sink (apply vector body-part
                                (for [i (range num)]
                                  (update body-part :name
                                          #(str/replace % #"^left" (str i))))))

              (conj sink body-part)))]

    (reduce transform-lefts [] asym-set)))
```

I also altered what you're doing in the `for` comprehension. You had a literal `{:name ..., :size size}` in there. This isn't good practice though. Pretend in the future you decide to add a new attribute to body parts. Maybe `:quality` or something. What happens if you forget to update `make-sym-parts`? Because you're reconstructing the map from scratch, the new body part will be discarded! [`update`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update) is like `assoc`, but it "updates" a previous value using a function instead of overwriting it like `assoc` does. The previous value is passed into the function, and the new value becomes whatever the function returns.

This could still be improved a bit by making use of `mapcat`. Right now, you're using `reduce` instead of `map` because in some cases, you need to add multiple entries per existing element. `mapcat` (basically short for "map then concatenate") can help here. It will automatically flatten the resulting list. This means you can get rid of the `sink` accumulator:

```
(defn make-sym-parts [asym-set num]
  (letfn [(transform-lefts [{:keys [name] :as body-part}]
            (if (str/starts-with? name "left-")
              [body-part
               (for [i (range num)]
                 (update body-part :name
                         #(str/replace % #"^left" (str i))))]

              [body-part]))]  ; Note how this requires a wrapping so it can be flattened

    (mapcat transform-lefts asym-set)))  ; Lazy!
```

The major drawback here is I wouldn't be surprised if this is slower. That likely isn't an issue though.

---

I was going to suggest you change `rand-part` to use `reduce` (I had a whole thing written up and everything!), then I realized that it requires knowledge of the next part in the list. It is still possible to use `reduce`, but it would require doing something messy like partitioning the list of parts into pairs, then reducing over the pairs. I think what you have here is likely neater.

I will mention though, just in case you didn't know, `reduce` allows for an early exit using [`reduced`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduced). If you didn't need to use `remaining` in the loop, that would allow your `loop` here to be written using `reduce`.

The only real two noteworthy things in `rand-part` are

- I would use `:keys` here to deconstruct `current`. You're using explicit key-access a lot which adds some bulk.
- `(reduce +` can also be written as `(apply +`. If you look at the [definition of `+`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/841fa60b41bc74367fb16ec65d025ea5bde7a617/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L985), it and most other binary operators have a var-arg overload to delegates to a reduction. It's not a big deal either way. From what I've seen, `(apply +` is generally regarded as more idiomatic, but not by much.

Something like:

```
(defn rand-part [parts]
  (let [size-sum (apply + (map :size parts))
        thresh (rand size-sum)]
    (loop [[{:keys [name size]} & remaining] parts
           sum size]
      (if (> sum thresh)
        name
        (recur remaining
               (+ sum (:size (first remaining))))))))
```

Good luck and welcome to Clojure!

Comment: Wow this is a lot. Thank you for your effort. I think I'll be back in a few weeks with a real project instead of a toy example :) It is awesome that you took the time to explain all this. Sadly I can't even upvote your answer since I dont have 15 reputation yet

Comment: @Uzaku No problem, I enjoy reviewing code. I'm looking forward to seeing what you come up with in the next couple weeks.